# RCP application splash screen on Linuxes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a working RCP application which was moved from eclipse 4.7 to 4.11  target platforms. The splash screen of the application is not rendered properly on Linuxes (I have tried Ubuntu 16.04 and Fedora 24). Not a single line changed in the code, so there is obviously something in the runtime which I need to address. Have no idea where to even start looking at this. It appears that the layout rendering is not respected properly.

Here is how the splash screen looks with Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen runtime:

[image]

And this is what I get with Eclipse 11 runtime. Seem like some CSS issues but this is an old code base, there are no CSS tricks. Pretty basic swt grid layout, same code:

[image]

On the latest Ubuntu (19) it looks even weirder, the radio buttons and check boxes are not painted properly when selected:

[image]

I don't see this issue neither on Windows nor on MacOS. 
Only on Linuxes. Any secret behind this?

Comment: Maybe something to do with different versions of GTK being used (see [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2015/03/20/identifying-the-gtk-version-your-eclipse-ide-is-using/) for identifying the versions).

Comment: @greg-449, thank you for the hint, I see these properies in configuration details: 
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.theme=Adwaita
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.version=3.20.6

Comment: I am giving up on this, displaying the controls in splash simply doesn't work with GTK. Will be popping up a modal dialog to prompt for the input on top of the splash. Which by the way also doesn't respect sizes and fonts, but at least I can re-size the shell to fit the controls in. With the splash it simply isn't possible because of the fixed size of the background image shown in the spash window.